# Spring Boot 3.x Upgrade Redis Two Bean were found

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis

After the spring upgrade,
"Parameter 0 of the constructor in com.exampe.redis.operation.RedisOperation required a single bean, but 2 were found:"
I'm getting the error.

spring-boot version: **3.2.2**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
  <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
        <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**My RedisConfiguration.java**

```
@AutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.redis"})
public class RedisConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

**My RedisOperation.java class**

```
@Component
public class RedisOperation {
    private ValueOperations valueOperations;

    public RedisOperation(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        this.valueOperations = redisTemplate.opsForValue();
    }
    ...
}
```

**resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports**
file content

```
com.exampe.redis.config.RedisConfiguration
```

**My Main Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
public class ExampleMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.data.redis.host=localhost
spring.data.redis.port=9088
```

**Error**

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.redis.operation.RedisOperation required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - redisTemplate: defined by method 'redisTemplate' in class path resource [com/example/redis/config/RedisConfiguration.class]
    - stringRedisTemplate: defined by method 'stringRedisTemplate' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/redis/RedisAutoConfiguration.class]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by marking the redisTemplate bean **@Primary**.

```
@Bean
@Primary
RedisTemplate redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
    return redisTemplate;
}
```